# Unable to locate element - Selenium Cookies

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

My Code:

```
        #Open Website
        profile_path = r'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ndefault-release'
        options = Options()
        options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
        options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
        options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")        
        service = Service(r'C:\Users\XXX\geckodriver.exe')
        driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)

        # declaration of variables 
        name = "x"
        suffix = "x"
        start_number = 1
        end_number = 1000

        for i in range(start_number, end_number):
            driver.get('https://www.bauhaus.info/')
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=f"/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button").click()
```

After executing i get following error:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: /div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button Stacktrace: RemoteError@chrome://remote/content/shared/RemoteError.jsm:12:1 WebDriverError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:192:5 NoSuchElementError@chrome://remote/content/shared/webdriver/Errors.jsm:404:5 element.find/</<@chrome://remote/content/marionette/element.js:291:16 PS C:\Users\Martin\Desktop\Selenium - Login2me>

I added this "driver.implicitly_wait(10)" so the element is there and also it seems that this cookie windows is not inside an addition iframe. cant figure out why i get this error.

[image]

Comment: Would you share the url? It may be inside iframe or shadowroot.

Comment: Thank you - shadowroot is the answer! i only checked for iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Cookie button is under shadowroot(open). so try the below code

```
element = driver.execute_script("""return document.querySelector('#usercentrics-root').shadowRoot.querySelector("button[data-testid='uc-accept-all-button']")""")
element.click()
```

Comment: Natrium2 - If this answered your question, please make sure that you accept the answer.